# What AI designs are suited for producing title replacements?

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, natural-language-processing

Problem: "For a given news article, generate another title for the article if the article is to be published under a different Publication."

Which algorithm will be well suited for this? Should I use naive Bayesian or any NLP algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a seq2seq LSTM model. Giving a article will generate a title for it.

- You need to train it on data which comprises news articles and their corresponding titles.

  You can refer [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/sequence-to-sequence-model-introduction-and-concepts-44d9b41cd42d) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/seq2seq-model-in-tensorflow-ec0c557e560f).

Comment: I think that  his model also needs to be conditional, because he needs to generate new titles from "different publications".